# Python Pandas has low CPU usage and not using all cores

Tags: pandas, multicore, windows-server

I have a Pandas script that runs at > 90% usage on my local core i5 Macbook. I am migrating it to a remote 16 core Windows Server 2008, but it only seems to use one of the 16 cores. The CPU usage is only < 10%.

Why would the same script use the processors differently? What could be the cause and solution to use all 16 cores on the Windows server?

I have read about Dask and other Python multiple core tools, but I'd prefer not to invest time in those and turn my algorithm into a parallel one.

Comment: Are those the same version? Python, pandas and multithread libraries?

Comment: @IsuruH Yes. I updated them both to the latest version. I'm not using any multithread libraries cuz it seems by default Mac balanced workload to all cores.

Comment: So that might be the reason. You have a single threaded program and one of the underlying OS decided to paralalise it to use all the available cores and one doesn't.

Comment: @IsuruH It's really a curious situation. Do you know how Mac OSX can parallelize the program? It makes little sense how it can do it automatically but Windows cannot.

Comment: Sorry OS is not my strongest, plus zero knowledge when it comes to Mac. But its not hard to assume one of the OSes employing techniques similar to "Thread Level Speculation" where a single threaded program is parallelized on the fly

Comment: Keep in mind that on a multi-core Mac, 100% means all of one core, not all processing available. 800% would be all cores at 100% on a 4 core (8 logical cores) Mac. Chances are you're not actually seeing different behavior between machines, just different reporting.